# What does it mean for (placement_params) the parentheses after new operator and before type in c++?

Tags: c++, new-operator, allocation

What does the first parenthesis do?

```
// TArray<struct FBatchedLine> BatchedLines;      // declared in LineBatchComponent.h

new(BatchedLines) FBatchedLine(Start, End, Color, LifeTime, Thickness, DepthPriority);
```

The [new operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) reference says it is a `placement_params`:

> If placement_params are provided, they are passed to the allocation function as additional arguments

I suppose it creates the object directly at the end of the given array `BatchedLines`, but I am not sure to understand fully how it works.

When are `placement_params` useful?

**Note**

For those who have an access to the github UnrealEngine repo, [here](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/97c8d3ef55e869e17ef149903eae2a33101381c9/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/Components/LineBatchComponent.cpp#L115) is the source file.

Comment: *To access our repositories, sign up for a free account at UnrealEngine.com and register your GitHub ID using these instructions.* - Yeah, you shouldn't count on everyone having done that.

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I didn't realized this. The link is not essential though.

Comment: "The new operator reference says it is a placement_params:", well, keep on reading.. it's right in the next line... *sigh*.

Comment: Yes I read them but I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: The next paragraph... Such allocation functions are known as "placement new", after the standard allocation function `void* operator new(std::size_t, void*)`, which simply returns its second argument unchanged. This is used to construct objects in allocated storage:

Comment: Is it likely that `BatchedLines` points to the BatchedLines[size of BatchedLines] so that the new FBatchedLine is constructed directly in the Array? This would be more efficient than `BatchedLines.Add(FBatchedLine(Start, End, Color, LifeTime, Thickness, DepthPriority));`? Even if FBatchLine implements the move operator?

Comment: @arthur.sw Placement `new` explicitly avoids the memory allocation which, heap or stack, is faster than potentially allocating and copying.  Moving is generally only more efficient than copying if there's indirect memory owned by the object (e.g. `std::string`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **placement new** syntax. It constructs an object of type `FBatchedLine` at the memory pointed to by `BatchedLines` with the constructor arguments `(Start, End, Color, LifeTime, Thickness, DepthPriority)`. After the call, `BatchedLines` can be used to reference the constructed object.

Informally, you could imagine invoking the constructor with `BatchedLines` being `this`.

Comment: To be clear, the object is created _in_ `BatchedLines`, not "after".

Answer (score 1):

The text: palcement_params is not explained in the [reference C++ page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). According to English meaning: where to put the pointer usually a location inside an array.  Here is a code example from boost

```
T* buffer;
size_t write_index;
new (buffer + write_index) T(t); // copy-construct
```

Essentially, you put a new object of type T into the write_index location of buffer.